# How to append a dictionary to another dictionary string key in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

**This is my input:**

```
Blue -> dress,jeans,hat
Gold -> dress,t-shirt,boxers
White -> briefs,tanktop
Blue -> dress,gloves
```

**What I want (result), dictonary which looks like this:**

```
result{Blue:{dress:2,jeans:1,hat:1,gloves:1}, 
Gold:{dress:1,t-shirt:1,boxers:1},
White:{briefs:1,tanktop:1}} #pseudo code
```

**What I tried:**

```
n = int(input())
result = {}

for i in range(1, n+1):
    input_row = input()
    input_parts = input_row.split(' -> ')
    color = input_parts[0]
    items = input_parts[1].split(',')

    for item in items:
        if color not in result:
            result[color] = color
        if item not in result[color]:
            dict_items = {item: }
            result[color] = dict_items
        else:
            result[color][item] += 1

print(result)
```

**The problem comes from this part, because it always overwrite (normal) it:**

```
result[color] = dict_items
```

I already tried with `.append`, `.setdefault`, `.update` without any result.

Other solutiong might be `collections.counter`.

Comment: Can you fix your formatting? It's hard to see what's going on here.

Comment: @brunns done, sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `collections.defaultdict` and `Counter`

**Ex:**

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

n = int(input())
result = defaultdict(Counter)

for i in range(1, n+1):
    input_row = input()
    input_parts = input_row.split(' -> ')
    color = input_parts[0]
    items = input_parts[1].split(',')

    #for item in items:
    #    result[color] += Counter((item,))
    result[color] += Counter(items) #Thanks Sam Mason

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
defaultdict(<class 'collections.Counter'>, 
{'Blue': Counter({'dress': 2, 'gloves': 1, 'jeans': 1, 'hat': 1}), 
'White': Counter({'briefs': 1, 'tanktop': 1}), 
'Gold': Counter({'t-shirt': 1, 'dress': 1, 'boxers': 1})})
```

---

*Without imports*

```
n = int(input())
result = {}

for i in range(1, n+1):
    input_row = input()
    input_parts = input_row.split(' -> ')
    color = input_parts[0]
    items = input_parts[1].split(',')

    if not color in result:
        result[color] = {}

    for item in items:
        if item not in result[color]:
            result[color].update({item: 0})     #to update dict use the dict.update() methid
        result[color][item] += 1

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
{'Blue': {'dress': 2, 'gloves': 1, 'hat': 1, 'jeans': 1},
 'Gold': {'boxers': 1, 'dress': 1, 't-shirt': 1},
 'White': {'briefs': 1, 'tanktop': 1}}
```

Comment: Upvote, but i'm also notice about this solution, is there other solution ?

Comment: Sorry I do not understand?

Comment: You provide me solution about my problem, but i'm also looking for "How to append a dictionary to another dictionary string key in Python3". Also at the end of my question I'm notice about `collections.counter`.

Comment: why not just do `result[color] += Counter(items)`, instead of the for loop?

Comment: @SamMason. I did not think of that. Sorry. :(

Answer (score 2):

An alternative method is to use `defaultdict(int)` on its own:

```
from collections import defaultdict
# same as your method ...
n = int(input())
result = {}

for i in range(1, n+1):
    input_row = input()
    input_parts = input_row.split(' -> ')
    color = input_parts[0]
    items = input_parts[1].split(',')

    # differs from your method from here on:
    results[color] = defaultdict(int) if color not in results else results[color]
    for item in items:
        results[colour][item] += 1
```

I would use Rakesh's `Counter` method though.